# mysql: Insert with values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, dml

i got 3 Tables

```
Player: player_id, player_name

Date: date_id, date_value

PlayerOnDate: pod_id, player_id, date_id
```

how can i inser something like

```
INSERT INTO `playerondate`(`player_on_date_id`, `player_id`, `date_date_id`) VALUES (
  NULL,
  SELECT player_id 
    WEHRE player_name LIKE 'aName',
  SELECT date_id 
    WEHRE date_value LIKE '12122015'
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a specific SQL statement for that INSERT INTO ... SELECT

```
INSERT INTO `playerondate`(`player_on_date_id`, `player_id`, `date_date_id`)
SELECT NULL, player_id, date_id 
FROM playerondate
WHERE player_name = 'aName' AND date_value LIKE '12122015'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a FROM

```
SELECT player_id FROM Player WHERE player_name = 'aName',
SELECT date_id FROM `Date` WHERE date_value LIKE '12122015'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html